# How do I display data from a JSON object using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New programmer here learning ReactJS. I have some code that uses axios to make an HTTP request to get XMLData from a local file. Then on the response, I am using xml-js to turn that XML data into a JSON object. Then, I am taking that `jsonObj` and saving it to a state using `setState()`.

I have a function `renderTableRows()` that is supposed to return JSX to display my JSON data on the browser. I destructured the state and try to console log from the `renderTableRows()` but when I try to access `users.result.body` I get

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined".

When I do it from the `then()` within the `componentDidMount()` I am able to access the data. I have also include an excerpt of the data I am reading at the bottom of the code.

I'd like to iterate using `map()` through all the row array attributes. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      users: []
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(XMLData, {
      "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
    })
    .then((response) => {
      var jsonObj = convert.xml2js(response.data,{compact:true, spaces: 4});
      this.setState({users:jsonObj});
      //console.log(this.state.users.result.body.row[0].col[0]);
    });
  }

  renderTableHeader = () => {
   return <th>
            <td>Division Full Path</td>
            <td>Billable Hours</td>
            <td>Vacation Hours Only</td>
            <td>Total Hours</td>
          </th>
  }

  renderTableRows = () => {
    const {users} = this.state
   console.log(users.result.body);
    return <h1>Hello from table rows</h1>
  }

  render() {
    //const { users } = this.state

    return <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  {this.renderTableHeader()}
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  {this.renderTableRows()}
                </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
  }  

 "header": {
    "col": [
        {
            "label": {
                "_text": "Counter Source Date"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": {
                "_text": "Employee Id"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": {
                "_text": "Counter Hours"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": {
                "_text": " Division Full Path"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": {
                "_text": " Projects/Equip/Vessels\nBillable"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": {
                "_text": "Counter Name"
            }
        }
    ]
}  

"body": {
        "row": [
            {
                "col": [
                    {
                        "_text": "01/01/2021"
                    },
                    {
                        "_text": "2183"
                    },
                    {
                        "_text": "8.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "_text": "01 - Fort Lauderdale/Salvage"
                    },
                    {
                        "_text": "No"
                    },
                    {
                        "_text": "Holiday"
                    }
                ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

## Issue

The initial state doesn't match how it is accessed in `renderTableRows`.

```
this.state = {
  users: []
}
```

Here `this.state.users` is an array, so `this.state.users.result` is undefined. This is fine until you then attempt to access a `body` property and the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined` is thrown.

## A Solution

You can either start with valid initial state:

```
this.state = {
  users: {
    result: {}
  }
}
```

Or use a bunch of guard clauses in `renderTableRows`:

```
renderTableRows = () => {
  const { users } = this.state
  console.log(users.result && users.result.body);
  return <h1>Hello from table rows</h1>
}
```

Or use Optional Chaining:

```
renderTableRows = () => {
  const { users } = this.state
  console.log(users.result?.body);
  return <h1>Hello from table rows</h1>
}
```

Since you mention wanting to map through the rows the first option isn't what you want. If rendering rows it'll be something like:

```
renderTableRows = () => {
  const {users} = this.state
  return users.map(user => (....))
}
```

## Update

I suggest setting your state to `jsonObj.result` properties, this is so you don't need to access the `result` property each render, it just shortens the access. Map `this.state.users.headerColumns` to the header columns and map `this.state.rows` to each row and additionally map the row columns.

```
class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: {
        headerColumns: [],
        rows: [],
      }
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(XMLData, {
        "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
      })
      .then((response) => {
        var jsonObj = convert.xml2js(response.data, {
          compact: true,
          spaces: 4
        });
        this.setState({ users: {
          headerColumns: jsonObj.header.col,
          rows: jsonObj.body.row
        } });
      });
  }

  renderTableHeader = () => {
    const { users: { headerColumns } } = this.state;
    return (
      <th>
        {headerColumns.map(col => (
          <td key={col.label._text}>{col.label._text}</td>
        ))}
        <td>Total Hours</td>
      </th>
    );
  };

  renderTableRows = () => {
    const { users: { rows } } = this.state;
    return rows.map((row, index) => {
      let computedTotal;
      return (
      <tr key={index}>
        {row.col.map((value, index) => {
          // compute time total from row data
          return (
            <td key={index}>{value}</td>
            );
          })}
          <td>{computedTotal}</td>
      </tr>
    )});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>{this.renderTableHeader()}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.renderTableRows()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have updated the state and added the data that I get from the object. I have added the header attribute that has a `col` array which contains 6 attributes containing the table headers.  The body contains a `rows` array of 10,000 arrays `col` which contain 6 objects that match the headers. I would like to be able to iterate through `row` arrays, access each column, add the total time and display it on the browser.

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested. I am now getting > Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'col'  of undefined.

Comment: @C33J4Y Which `col` access are you referring to? I based the accesses on your shared schema.

Comment: When I try to set the state  `this.setState({ users: {
          headerColumns: jsonObj.header.col,
          rows: jsonObj.body.row
        } });` I get the error. I get it for both the `col` and `row`.

Comment: @C33J4Y As I said, I based the accesses on your shared schema. What is the *actual* `jsonObj` then when you are processing the GET request?